# método para saber tener un id que autoincremente cada vez que cree un objeto de esa clase

Tags: java-swing

Tengo una clase cita y tiene una id, una clase doctor que tiene un array de citas. Ahora tengo un matriz de doctores cada posición del array tiene una tiene un array de nombres otra un array de consultas, etc. 
Os dejo como monto el array y se cargar en un combobox.

```
public void inicializarMedicos() {
        int i;
        int[] idsD = {0, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1};
        String[] nombres = {"", "José Guerrero Castro", "Juan Ruiz Luque", "Marta Jaén García", "Ana Pérez Martín", "Elena Díaz López"};
        int[] comsultas = {0, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1};
        String[] especialidad = {"", "Cirugía", "Medicina General", "Pediatría", "Pediatría", "Medicina General"};
        Doctor nuevoDoctor;
        listaDoctoresG = new ArrayList<>();
        for (i = 0; i < idsD.length; i++) {
            nuevoDoctor = new Doctor(idsD[i], especialidad[i], nombres[i], comsultas[i], listaCitas);
            listaDoctoresG.add(nuevoDoctor);
        }
    }

    public void cargaListaMedicos() {
        int i;
        int seleccionado = cmbEspecialidad.getSelectedIndex();
        String puestoCombo3;
        String especialidad = "";
        cmbDoctor.removeAllItems();
        listaDocFiltrados = new ArrayList<>();
        switch (seleccionado) {
            case 0:
                especialidad = "";
                break;
            case 1:
                especialidad = "Cirugía";
                break;
            case 2:
                especialidad = "Medicina general";
                break;
            case 3:
                especialidad = "Pediatría";
                break;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < listaDoctoresG.size(); i++) {
            Doctor d = listaDoctoresG.get(i);
            if (especialidad.compareToIgnoreCase(d.getEspecialidad()) == 0) {
                listaDocFiltrados.add(d);
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < listaDocFiltrados.size(); i++) {
            puestoCombo3 = listaDocFiltrados.get(i).getNombreDoctor();
            cmbDoctor.addItem(puestoCombo3);
        }
    }
```

Ahora os dejo mi idea para ese ID auto incremental

```
int idC = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listaDoctoresG.size(); i++) {
            if (listaDoctoresG.get(i).getNombreDoctor().compareToIgnoreCase(cmbDoctor.getSelectedItem().toString()) == 0) {
                idC = listaDoctoresG.get(i).getListaCitas().size()+1;
            }
        }
```

La idea es que según el doctor que hemos elegido lo busque en la lista lo saque y de la lista de citas de dicho doctor coja el tamaño y le sume 1 de manera que
cuando vayamos a meter el primer elemento el tamaño es 0 y le sumamos 1 obteniendo un id de 1.
El problema es que listaDoctoresG.get(i).getListaCitas() da null.

Comment: Si estás en un escenario real, lo correcto aquí sería usar una base de datos donde guardes la información en tablas que podrían estar o no relacionadas entre sí.

Comment: No es real y no puedo usar una base datos el ejercicio va asi